# Facebook Developer Timeline Preview

Tags: facebook-timeline

I hate to ask these type of questions but I am in a bind and need to get this in order. I fulfilled the prerequisite to get access to the developer preview of Timeline. I must have dismissed the dialog with the nice little "Get it now" button and now I can't get it back.

Is this a one time only offer, is there a way to get reasked, was there a time limit, etc?

I tried deleting and remaking an application with open graph etc.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/ajax/timeline/activate.php?action=activate&ref=profile_megaphone try this link or http://www.facebook.com/ajax/timeline/activate.php or something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://facebooktut.com/facebook-news/how-to-activate-facebook-timeline-developer-preview/) to a good tutorial how to get the invite again or just do it manually.

Comment: Believe me I did spend a whole afternoon on this, I'll check it out thanks. Edit: That same tutorial I have seen on countless sites and for me it's just not giving me the end result. I am intrigued and would be very much pleased to hear from you how to do it manually as you said. Thanks again.

Comment: Check the tutorial, as it says, go to the open graph and 'get started'. If you can't make it work, you need to describe why and what your problem is. 'It doesn't work' is always REALLY helpful! And go to superuser.com , SO is for programming questions!

Comment: Yes a million time, I am not this clueless I really thought I was on a StackExchange site I followed Facebook support link to here which is facebook.stackoverflow.com, I get it. Pretty embarrasing and nevermind. Stupid question.